# Manipulating big array in a more memory-efficient way

Tags: php, arrays, memory, memory-limit

I'm currently writing an API for an app that interfaces with a large database and need to retrieve large amounts of data from it, then spit it out as JSON.

I'm using CodeIgniter (CI) as a database interface but I don't think it's relevant here. I'm running into memory limits and I have unfortunately no way of increasing the limit because the shared hosting service won't do it.

I get about 56k rows from the database, which get put into an array by CI (zero-indexed, pretty standard). Each row has 7 fields.

All is well until I start looping through the array to modify data. The script runs into a memory limit error after a few loop iterations even though I'm just modifying the original array, and not allocating new variables, I think.

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
```

Below is the code I'm using:

```
$query = $this->db->get('table');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $result = $query->result_array();
    foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
        foreach($v as $key => $value) {
            if ($key === 'column_name') {
                $result[$k][$key] = json_decode($value);
                continue;
            }
            if ($value == null) {
                $result[$k][$key] = '';
            } else if (ctype_digit($value)) {
                $result[$k][$key] = (int) $result[$k][$key];
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Just decoding some json and casting to integers or empty strings, nothing fancy. But I will get memory limit errors on any line that mutates the `$result` array. Even if I remove the (memory-intensive) `json_decode` I will still get an error on line that simply casts to an `int`.

What's more, even if I remove the whole `foreach`, I get a memory limit error later on when I use `json_encode` to generate the API response.

I'm totally lost, and I really need this amount of data to be output all at once, no idea how to make this more memory-efficient (maybe with like buffers or something? never dived into this).

**EDIT**: for anyone interested, I managed to cut down on memory usage somewhat by making an unbuffered query to the database. This way, only 1 copy of the data is stored in the array. I also removed the foreach and treat each field specifically. The main problem, however, is probably how [PHP stores arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38558486/3446439). Here's the new code:

```
$query = $this->db->get('table');
$result = [];
while ($row = $query->unbuffered_row('array')) {
    if ($row['column1'] == '[]') {
        $row['column1'] = [];
    } else {
        $row['column1'] = json_decode($row['column1']);
    }
    $row['column2'] = (int) $row['column2'];
    $row['column3'] = (int) $row['column3'];
    $row['column4'] = is_null($row['column4']) ? '' : (int) $row['column4'];
    $row['column5'] = is_null($row['column5']) ? '' : (int) $row['column5'];

    $result[] = $row;
}

return $result;
```

Comment: What is the PHP memory limit setting?

Comment: @user2182349 the error message states `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`. Will add this to the question thanks.

Comment: Double it - you should be fine

Comment: `Foreach` copies the array it itterates over. [Manual: In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Or use a `for` or `do... while` loop

Comment: @Michel thanks, I suspected something similar. I read it's absolutely not advised to use assignment by reference with foreach so I might go simple loop. But yeah there is something fishy with my memory amount, I'll need to contact the hosting provider.

Comment: @Michel turns out that even using a for loop, I run into the same issue at some point when mutating a value in the array, so foreach is probably not to blame here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to tackle this, the real question would be what are your priorities?

- Does it have to be fast? can it be slow?
- Is that low-memory server is the absolute only resource available?

The ideal solution would obviously be upgrading your server, assuming you have tasks that consume a lot of memory, that should be a concern for whoever is running this project.

There is obviously the modern way to do it using micro services, each one of them processing a chunk of the data. They could be either written by you, or you could use cloud services such as AWS.

Having said that, assuming that you are indeed limited to the current constellation and you simply have no other option but to use a limited memory server for processing big data, I would recommend using local file I/O - it's not the fastest solution, but if you read chunks of data and keep writing them into a temporary file you will save the memory issue, and you could then flush that file to the client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am indeed quite limited by this server, and I hope they messed something up on their side and the server should have more memory, but I won't be sure until tomorrow when the support resumes. I could look into cloud services, that'd be an interesting experience. File IO is probably not an option since this has to be somewhat fast, but I'll do a test to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: If they want it to be fast they should give you more resources, for the very least control over the php.ini :)
Good luck!

Comment: BTW - I'm not sure how your server-client is setup, but if this query is done using an API call, you could try to simply keep outputting the data (echo) instead of storing it in an array, this might work.

Another workaround would be using EventSource, which is some kind of a web socket that keeps the connection live between the client and the server (html5 required)

Comment: Yeah I totally agree, I emailed by boss to ask them to upgrade to a dedicated server. The idea to echo out the data is not half bad but I need to output json so there is some work involved to make sure everything is properly formatted, and it's not a guarantee that I'll be able to have the full database result in memory anyway, in which case I'd have to do some unbuffered mysql requests. For now I managed to make several requests to the API instead of one but it's not ideal.